Existence of smooth functions decaying fast near the boundary
This question concerns the following claim: Let $M$ be a manifold and $U\subset M$ be open. For every smooth function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a smooth function $g:M\to[0,1]$ such that $g$ is strictly positive on $U$, vanishes outisde $U$, and the function
$$
fg(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)g(x)&~x\in U,
\\
0&~x\notin U,
\end{cases}
$$
is smooth on $M$.
This cannot be solved directly using bump functions, since we are not assuming that $\operatorname{supp}g\subset U$.
I have been thinking about this for a while. An idea is to take a compact exhaustion of $U$, take a sequence of bump functions $h_i$ on those compact sets, choose bounds on the derivatives of $h_i$ and $h_if$, and finally consider a power series of the form similar to $\sum_i2^{-i}\frac{1}{1+C_i+D_i}$, where $C_i,D_i$ are the bounds. This idea comes from the bottom of page 28 on the book $C^\infty$-Differentiable Spaces by Juan A. Navarro González.
However, I don't know how to prove this rigorously. The proof given in the book is unclear because it does not specify computing the derivative in which coordinate charts, and it does not provide full details.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have a different proof, please feel free to include it!

The following proof results from my discussion with Prof. John Lee. His comments and suggestions are very helpful.

Step 1. First suppose that $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
Cover $U$ by countably many balls $B(x_i,r_i)$ satisfying $\overline{B(x_i,2r_i)}\subset U$. For each $i$, choose a bump function $\psi_i$ such that $\psi_i=1$ on $\overline{B(x_i,r_i)}$ and $\operatorname{supp}\psi_i\subset B(x_i,2r_i)$. Then the function $\psi_if$ is well defined by extension to 0 outside $U$.
Let $C_i>0$ (resp. $D_i>0$) be positive constants that bound the absolute values of all partial derivatives of $\psi_i$ (resp. $\psi_if$) up to order $i$ on $\overline{B(x_i,2r_i)}$, and hence on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $\psi_i$ and $\psi_if$ are supported in $B(x_i,2r_i)$. Consider the function
$$
g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\frac{\psi_i(x)}{1+C_i+D_i}.
$$
Clearly $0<g<1$ on $U$ and $g=0$ outside $U$. To show that $g$ is smooth, let $\partial_k$ denote any $k$th partial derivative. Then
$$
2^{-i}\frac{\partial_k\psi_i}{1+C_i+D_i}<2^{-i},
$$
provided that $i>k$. Hence, the series of partial derivatives of $g$ converge uniformly, and so $g$ is smooth. A similar consideration shows that
$$
fg(x)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\frac{\psi_if(x)}{1+C_i+D_i}
$$
is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^n$, as required.
Step 2. Now, for the general case, suppose that $U\subset M$.
Cover $M$ by coordinate balls $\{B_\alpha\}$, each of which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that the conclusion in step 1 remains trivially true if $U$ is empty. For each $\alpha$, $U\cap B_\alpha$ is an open subset of $B_\alpha$ (possibly empty). The function $f:U\cap B_\alpha\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, and so by step 1 there exists a smooth function $g_\alpha:B_\alpha\to[0,1]$ such that $0<g_\alpha<1$ on $U\cap B_\alpha$, $g_\alpha=0$ on $B_\alpha\setminus U$, and $g_\alpha f$ is smooth on $B_\alpha$. Choose a partition of unity $\{\psi_\alpha\}$ on $M$ subordinate to the open cover $\{B_\alpha\}$. Then the function
$$
g=\sum_\alpha\psi_\alpha g_\alpha
$$
is smooth on $M$. We argue that $0<g<1$ on $U$ and $g=0$ outside $U$. To see this, note first that each $g_\alpha$ satisfies $0\le g_\alpha\le1$, and so any convex linear combination of values of $g_\alpha$ must also lie in $[0,1]$. Furthermore, for all $x\in U$, there is at least one $\alpha_0$ for which $x\in U\cap B_{\alpha_0}$, whence $g_{\alpha_0}(x)>0$. Finally, if $x\notin U$, then $g_\alpha(x)=0$ for all $\alpha$, whence $g(x)=0$.
It remains to check that $gf$ is smooth on $M$. Indeed, we have
$$
gf=\sum_\alpha\psi_\alpha\cdot(g_\alpha f),
$$
where $g_\alpha f$ is smooth on $B_\alpha$. But since $\operatorname{supp}\psi_\alpha\subset B_\alpha$, the functions $\psi_\alpha\cdot(g_\alpha f)$ are well defined and smooth on $M$. Since $\{\psi_\alpha\}$ is a partition of unity, $gf$ is also smooth on $M$.  $\blacksquare$
